# Can't plot my time series data and training data on the same graph, with different colours?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, training-data, autoplot

Im trying to plot both the original data and my training data on the same graph with this code:

```
timeseries <- ts(df$new_cases_per_million, start=c(2021,2), end=c(2022,3), frequency=52)
ts_train <- window(timeseries,start=c(2021,2),end=c(2022,3))
ts_test  <- window(timeseries,start=c(2022,3))

autoplot(ts_train3,xlab="Year",series="ts_train3") + 
  autolayer(ts_test3,series = "Test set3") +
  ggtitle("timeseries plot")
```

However when I execute this code, the graph only plots the original data, and not my trained data:
[image]

I also get this error with my plot:

> geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

I want it to look something like this:
[image: plot with original data and training data]

Comment: How could you get a red line when the test data is just a single and the last observation of train data?

Comment: yeah, I just realised by looking at my training data set. Thanks Mohanasundaram.

Comment: How can i change it so that, im testing more than 1 observation? My time series is only from 2021/2 to 2022/3.

Comment: Maybe you could change `end=c(2021,52)` in `ts_train` and `start=c(2022,1)` in `ts_test`.

Comment: Yeah, i tried that but it didn't work, its the same graph but with the red line starting at 2022.

Comment: You have to decide on the ranges for train data and test data and specify the start and end periods accordingly.